# Mils for milliliters

Tags: word-usage

My little grandson who lives in Sydney keeps saying 'mils' instead of 'milliliters' or 'ml'.  I thought at first it was his creation. Then I heard my son say 'mils' to me too but I taught him 'ml' or 'milliliters' at home. Is 'mils' a mainstream word?

Comment: It's perfectly normal chem lab jargon.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you see a label, **10 ml** and you wish to read it out loud.

You can say "ten milliliters" or "ten mils"  (Note that some people might say "ten mil" and that would be less grammatical but scientifically acceptable).

---

**Notes**

1. You do not pronounce 'ml' as "em el"  if that is what you mean.
2. **1 ml** is pronounced "one mil."

Comment: Oh, that. But labels say 10ML or 10ml,  not 10 MLS or 10mls. And it happens that I haven't heard 'mils' spoken in my country. We say 10 "em el". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit.

Comment: I was a science major in college in US. "Mils" was not considered "correct" from an education perspective but would be understood in most contexts. The full word"milliliters" was used. This was also true of quantities like kilograms (key-lows was colloquially used on occasion), centimeters, and the like. Celcius rather than centigrade is far better understood. But outside of science, we still use feet, inches, Fahrenheit, quarts, etc.

Comment: @Stu - It's an interesting point because I think 'mils' is a special case. I have never heard anyone say 'kils' for kilograms for example.  Clearly if you want to be precise, especially when making up medication or performing an important chemical procedure it's best to use the word in full. I don't know why school teachers tend to use 'mils' or if it is more widespread than that.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Of course people don't say "kils", they say "kilos".  But "milos" just doesn't sound right, and is too easily confused with, eg, "miles".  (There's nothing "wrong" with "mils" when speaking of a milliliter measurement.  It is "slang", of course, but readily understood and easily justifiable.)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "kils", no, but "k's" /kays/ I have heard for kgs. Worst short form I've ever heard (her in the Netherlands) is /uggehl/ for micrograms per liter, since the Greek μ looks like a u in  μg/l. As an aside, label that use M (mega) instead of m (milli) should not be taken too seriously.

Comment: @oerkelens - It wasn't long ago that strict guidelines had to be imposed on  UK doctors when prescribing drugs. They would write mg or μg and it was not unknown for a patient to die because of the pharmacist being unable to tell the difference in the doctors handwriting.

Answer (score 2):

Mils is acceptable but not mainstream

> **[mils:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mils)**
>   4. (used formerly in pharmaceutical prescriptions) a milliliter.

Normally, I would say M-L and use mils in the sense of *1/1000th of an inch* or *a million*.

Comment: What would you say if you came across a megalitre (`Ml`)?

Comment: I think M-L is too hackneyed for megalitre. I would just call it megalitre.

Answer (score 0):

[SI units](http://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/) follow a strict syntax that communicates the physical quantities without ambiguity. For example, in *ms*, *m* is called a *prefix* (to s) and it stands for *milli* (1/1000), and *s* stands for *second*, the SI unit for time.

Interestingly, according to the official site, the litre *L* is not an SI unit, but it admits SI prefixes. So *mL* (notice that the capitalisation of the basic unit *L* is retained) is one thousandth of a litre, and $ML$ would be one million litres. The unit of measure is written as a suffix to the number representing how many units are being described. For example, 5mL means five millilitres. To avoid ambiguity, the units should never have a trailing *s*. The characters *5mLs* translate to *5 millilitre-seconds*, not *5 millilitres*.

In mainstream usage, though, the finer points are often ignored and the syntactic unit is treated as if it was a word.

So strictly speaking, you're correct - *mils* is not a proper word in this context. However, you can consider it a modern colloquial term that is more common in the West than it is in the East.

As a point of interest, [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/ml) includes audio pronunciations of "ml" (*sic*), with the US version pronounced as *mil* and the UK version pronounced as *millilitre*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to disagree in regards to slang use in US. Here's why:

1) MIL in US is the slang term for one million dollars making it awkward in a society that typically uses ounces and teaspoons as units of liquid measurement

2) KILO is most commonly used in crime dramas as slang for (specifically) a kg of cocaine. And most people use pounds as unit of weight.

"Modern" use of measurements are not used as slang in US except in the examples I just listed (and I'm sure a few others). If one were abbreviating liquid quantity in academics in US (native speaker), they would say "mils" not "mil" for anything greater than 1. At least in my experience in Midwest and West Coast, but there may be some regional differences.

Comment: How much time have you spent in even a high school chemistry lab?

Comment: Ha, ha! I really shouldn't answer ... 11 years post high school. And now I write fiction! Land of the free ...

Comment: The point is that outside a lab, in America, there are mutiple meanings for "mil", which can lead to confusion. When I see/hear "mil", I immediately think of a thickness measure,    .001 inch.  Secondly I might think of "millimeter", and thirdly "million" —depending on context ("3 mil polyethylene", "3 mil of rain" "a cool 3 mil").